# XCode: Apple Mach-O Linker Error with New iOS 6 while adding self created static library

Tags: ios, ios6, static-libraries, linker-errors, ios-frameworks

I am created **static library** files  and added that in to **My Project XCode** while compile it's throughs  **Apple Mach-O Linker Error**,

```
My Static libraries
1.libMathLibrary.a
2.libDineshLibrary.a
```

I have checked

1. **Target->Build Phases ->Link Binary with Libraries** my static library added
2. **LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "$(SRCROOT)/staticlb/libMathLibrary" "$(SRCROOT)/staticlb/libDineshLibrary"**  add static library path.

How to I resolve this problem. Please share your ideas, I hope it will help me..Thank you.

Comment: which linker error are you getting ?

Comment: libDineshLibrary static library link error     Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_libDineshLibrary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o

Comment: make sure that you have added all the required frameworks.

Comment: I found when i created static library in simulator mode it will support xcode with simulator compelling  only when it compile in device it will through linker errors vise-versa in device also.

Comment: This is link I referred to create static library: http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/

Answer (score 0):

I found solution for my problem

After created your own **static .a extension library** files

```
1. **libdevice.a** (device mode compile static library file)
2. **libsimulator.a** (simulator mode compile static library file)
```

Please **convert two compile mode static libraries to one common static .a extension library**

in your **terminal**

**`lipo -create libdevice.a libsimulator.a -output libcommonlibrary.a`**

**The new  libcommonlibrary.a common static library file will support both simulator and device compilation.**

please ref link: http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/15/how-to-create-universal-static-libraries-on-xcode-4/